# Removing border from tab ui control

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-theme

I have the following script:

http://jsfiddle.net/2HNvL/

but I can't seem to remove the light gray border around the tab control.  Anyone here know how to do that?

I have tried the following:

```
    #tabs .ui-widget { border:none;  padding:0px; margin:0px; }
    #tabs .ui-widget-header { border:none; display:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
    #tabs .ui-widget-content { border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
```

But that does not work.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Adding to your list a simple `#tabs {border: none}` should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming I understand your question correctly you want to remove the border around the text

> Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo,
>   vehicula tempus, commodo a,

If that is the case, your one selector is wrong for `.ui-widget-content`

```
 #tabs .ui-widget-content { border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
```

Is looking for a child element of `.ui-widget-content` with a parent of `#tabs`

If you change it to this:

```
#tabs.ui-widget-content { border:none; padding:0px; margin:0px; }
```

Will target only an element with an id of tabs and a class of `.ui-widget-content`

Updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/2HNvL/4/).

Comment: Why does this indent the text below the buttons?

Answer (score 0):

give the buttons a class, and remove the border from that class..

http://jsfiddle.net/2HNvL/3/

```
<input type="button" value="button1" id="button1" class='noBorder' />
```

...

```
.noBorder{border:none;}
```